# Bash sort by regexp

Tags: linux, bash, sorting, console

I have something about 100 files with the following syntax

```
ahfsdjfhdfhj_EPI_34_fdsafasdf
asdfasdf_EPI_2_fdsf
hfdjh_EPI_8_dhfffffffffff
ffffffffffasdfsdf_EPI_1_fyyy44

...
```

There is always EPI_NUMBER. How can I sort it by this number?

Comment: Can the strings _before_ `_EPI_` contain `_`, and is the number always followed by an `_` too?

Answer (score 13):

From your example it appears that delimiter is `_` and text `EPI_nnn` comes at the same position after delimiter `_`. If that is always the case then you can use following command to sort the file:

```
sort -n -t "_" -k 3 file.txt
```

**UPDATE:**

If position of `EPI_` text is not *fixed* then use following shell command:

```
sed 's/^\(.*EPI_\)\(.*\)$/\2##\1/' file.txt | sort -n -t "_" -k1 | sed 's/^\(.*\)##\(.*\)$/\2\1/'
```

Comment: sorry there are also files like h_fd_fds_fdjh_EPI_8_dhfffffffffff

Comment: Pls see my updated answer if that is the case. Or else you can use codaddict's answer as well in Perl.

Answer (score 4):

If Perl is okay you can:

```
print sort foo <>;    
sub foo {
        ($x = $a) =~s/.*EPI_(\d+).*/$1/;
        ($y = $b) =~s/.*EPI_(\d+).*/$1/;
        return $x <=> $y;
}
```

and use it as:

```
perl prg.pl inputfile
```

[See it](http://www.ideone.com/pYnLc)

Answer (score 3):

```
 sed -e 's/EPI_/EPI /' file1 file2 ...|sort -n -k 2 -t ' '
```

Pipe that to `sed -e 's/ /_/'` to get back the original form.

Comment: `ls | sed 's/.*EPI_//' | sort -n | while read a; do echo `ls | grep ${a}`; done` Solved my problem

Comment: See also: https://superuser.com/a/79359/128768, although it might not work as the part to sort is not in the end of the string. ?

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you:

```
 ls | sed 's/.*EPI_\([0-9]*\)/\1 &/' | sort -n | sed 's/\S* //'
```