# Linux grep and sort log files

Tags: linux, sorting, logging, grep

I looked almost everywhere ([there](http://leftbrainnie.blogspot.be/2009/01/merge-log-files-and-sort-records-in.html), [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8680561/bash-sort-by-regexp), [there](https://superuser.com/questions/148456/merging-and-sorting-multiple-files-with-sort), [there](https://superuser.com/questions/822261/merge-by-date-multiple-log-files-that-also-include-un-dated-lines-e-g-stack-tr) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24012484/merging-mutiple-log-files-by-timestamp-in-2nd-column)) with no luck.

What I have here is a bunch of log files in a directory, where I need to look for a specific ID (myID) and sort the output by date. Here is an example :

in file1.log :

```
2015-09-26 15:39:50,788 - DEBUG - blabla : {'id' : myID}
```

in file2.log:

```
2015-09-26 15:39:51,788 - ERROR - foo : {'id' : myID}
```

in file3.log:

```
2015-09-26 15:39:48,788 - ERROR - bar : {'id' : myID}
```

Exepected output :

```
2015-09-26 15:39:48,788 - ERROR - bar : {'id' : myID}
2015-09-26 15:39:50,788 - DEBUG - blabla : {'id' : myID}
2015-09-26 15:39:51,788 - ERROR - foo : {'id' : myID}
```

What I am doing now (and it works pretty well), is :

```
grep -hri --color=always "myID" | sort -n
```

The only problem is that with the -h option of grep, the file names are hidden. I'd like to keep the file names AND keep the sorting.
I tried :

```
grep -ri --color=always "myID" | sort -n -t ":" -k1,1 -k2,2
```

But it doesn't work. Basically, the grep command outputs the name of the file followed by ":", I'd like to sort the results from this character.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Your dates have colons in them, and sort's fields are 1-based. Try `-k2`

Comment: Ok great, I had to remove the -n option.
The final command is : grep -ri --color=always "myID" | sort -k2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
grep --color=always "myID" file*.log | sort -t : -k2,2 -k3,3n -k4,4n
```

Output:

```
file3.log:2015-09-26 15:39:48,788 - ERROR - bar : {'id' : myID}
file1.log:2015-09-26 15:39:50,788 - DEBUG - blabla : {'id' : myID}
file2.log:2015-09-26 15:39:51,788 - ERROR - foo : {'id' : myID}
```

Comment: This still has `-n` which means that the `yyyy-mm-dd hh` column will be ignoring everything after the year. If you fix that, `-k3 -k4` becomes redundant, since `-k2` is using columns 2-to-end, not just 2.

Comment: @Cyrus For some reason, when I redirect the output to a file, it gives unwanted characters everywhere i.e this: ^[[m^[[K^[[36m^[[K:^[[m^[[KJul 14 15:57:47 instead of this: Jul 14 15:57:47

Comment: @vaibhavkumar: Your file seems to contain special characters. Check your file: `cat -A file` or `cat -v file`.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, a little bit longer but I think it should work:

```
 grep -l "myID" file* > /tmp/file_names && grep -hri "myID" file* | sort -n > /tmp/grep_result && paste /tmp/file_names /tmp/grep_result | column -s $'\t' -t
```

What it does basically is, first store files names by:

```
grep -l "myID" file* > /tmp/file_names
```

Store grep sorted results:

```
grep -hri "myID" file* | sort -n > /tmp/grep_result
```

Paste the results column-wise (using a tab separator):

```
paste /tmp/file_names /tmp/grep_result | column -s $'\t' -t
```

Answer (score 0):

The column ordering for sort is 1-based, so k1 will be your filename part. That means that in your attempt, you are sorting by filename, then by date and hour of your log line. Also, the `-n` means that you are using numeric ordering, which won't be playing nicely with yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss format (it will read `yyyy-mm-dd hh` as only the first number, i.e. the year).

You can use:

```
sort -t ":" -k2
```

Note that I specified column 2 as the start, and left the end blank. The end defaults to the end-of-line.

If you want to sort specific columns, you need to explicitly set the start *and* end, for example: `-k2,2`. You can use this to sort out-of-sequence columns, for example `-k4,4 -k2,2` will sort by column 4 and use column 2 for tie-breaking.

You could also use `-k2,4`, which would stop sorting at the colon just before your log details (i.e. it would use `2015-09-26 15:39:48,788 - ERROR - bar`)

Finally, perhaps you want to have your log files in a consistent order if the time is the same:

```
sort -t ":" -k2,4 -k1,1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try rust-based tool [*Super Speedy Syslog Searcher*](https://crates.io/crates/super_speedy_syslog_searcher)

(assuming you have [rust installed](https://www.rust-lang.org/tools/install))

```
cargo install super_speedy_syslog_searcher
```

then

```
s4 file1.log file2.log file3.log | grep "myID"
```

> The only problem is that with the -h option of grep, the file names are hidden. I'd like to keep the file names AND keep the sorting.

You could try

```
$ s4 --color=never -nw file1.log file2.log file3.log | grep "myID"
file1.log:2015-09-26 15:39:48,788 - ERROR - bar : {'id' : myID}
file2.log:2015-09-26 15:39:50,788 - DEBUG - blabla : {'id' : myID}
file3.log:2015-09-26 15:39:51,788 - ERROR - foo : {'id' : myID}
```