# Sort log file by a key=value field using command line

Tags: linux, bash, sorting

I have some gigabytes of logs and I'm trying to track worst execution times of a given method, So I used grep to filter the lines that matters

```
$ grep "m=a" /var/log/syslog* 
Sep 12 05:14:00 host1[716]: 2018-09-12 05:14:00.076 [MessageBroker-2] INF 1 com.acme m=a h_status=success, h_time=51, msg=some message
Sep 11 20:00:00 host1[716]: 2018-09-11 20:00:00.389 [MessageBroker-2] INF 1 com.acme m=a h_status=success, h_time=54, msg=some message
Sep 12 04:42:00 host1[716]: 2018-09-12 04:42:00.682 [MessageBroker-2] INF 1 com.acme m=a h_status=success, h_time=77, msg=some message
Sep 12 05:15:02 host1[716]: 2018-09-12 05:15:02.536 [Test worker    ] INF 2 com.acme m=a h_status=success, h_time=8, msg=some message
```

Now I want to sort this file in a desc order to get lines with the highest **h_time** field values. I tried to do that using sort but I have no success because I'm not getting how to extract h_time field value.

I searched how to use custom separators to identify custom fields using sort and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8680561/bash-sort-by-regexp) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17929210/bash-linux-sort-by-3rd-column-using-custom-field-seperator) anwser, no success.

How can I sort these lines in a desc order by a h_time field using some command line tool using a as simple as possible syntax?

Comment: If your final goal is just to extract a few lines with the highest time, you may not need to sort entire some GB log file unless you don't care about the processing time and/or your machine is powerful enough.

Comment: sorting according to custom fields works for your example input (`sort -t, -k2 -Vr log.txt`). so please provide some records from your log where using `sort` this way will fail

Comment: @tshiono at this GB of logs I grep by `h_time` and it gives me some thousand lines. Sorry I wasn't clear enough, I want to sort this thousand lines by h_time field. Of course I can use some other external tool to make this sort using the resulting file but I want to  know if it's possible to be done at command line in a easy way

Comment: Why downvote guys, maybe my question is not clear enough?

Comment: @oguzismail thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this. First use perl regex to replace and bring the numeric value at first as shown below then sort it. This way you can even display only the required information.

```
perl -pe 's/(.+)(h_time=\d+, )(.+)/\2\1\3/g' log | sort -V
```

Which gives:

```
h_time=51, Sep 12 05:14:00 host1[716]: 2018-09-12 05:14:00.076 [MessageBroker-2] INF 1 com.acme l=35 h_status=success, msg=some message
h_time=54, Sep 11 20:00:00 host1[716]: 2018-09-11 20:00:00.389 [MessageBroker-2] INF 1 com.acme l=35 h_status=success, msg=some message
h_time=77, Sep 12 04:42:00 host1[716]: 2018-09-12 04:42:00.682 [MessageBroker-2] INF 1 com.acme l=35 h_status=success, msg=some message
h_time=8, Sep 12 05:15:02 host1[716]: 2018-09-12 05:15:02.536 [Test worker    ] INF 2 com.acme l=35 h_status=success, msg=some message
```

Or if you want only some information:

```
perl -pe 's/(\w+ \d+ [\d:]+).+\[(.+)].+h_time=(\d+), .+/\3 ms\t\2\t\t\1/g' log | sort -V
```

Which gives:

```
8 ms    Test worker             Sep 12 05:15:02
51 ms   MessageBroker-2         Sep 12 05:14:00
54 ms   MessageBroker-2         Sep 11 20:00:00
77 ms   MessageBroker-2         Sep 12 04:42:00
```